# Extract items between 2 numbers in Ruby

Tags: ruby, algorithm

**Problem:**

- Given an array of numbers in Ruby, return the groups of numbers that appear between 1 and 2.
- The numbers 1 and 2 do not appear in between other 1's and 2's (there are no subsets of subsets).

**Example 1**

input: `[1, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2]`

output: `[[1, 3, 2], [1, 4, 2]]`

**Example 2**

`input:  [0, 1, 3, 2, 10, 1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 7, 5, 2, 3, 1, -400, 2, 12, 16]`

`output: [  [1, 3, 2],   [1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 7, 5, 2],  [1, -400, 2]       ]`

My hunch is to use a combination of `#chunk` and `#drop_while` or a generator.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This sounds like homework. What have you tried so far? Show your code.

Comment: Hi, this is not for academic purposes. I have a 4 GB log file with lines surrounded by the words`BEGIN` and `END` that I need to extract out. Here is my first attempt. I'd prefer a solution that uses lazy enumeration. https://gist.github.com/aussiDavid/bc0c1f0b9a02dd9e6c308db1e64ab5f9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an option using [Enumerable#slice_when][1]:

```
ary1 = [1, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2]
ary2 = [0, 1, 3, 2, 10, 1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 7, 5, 2, 3, 1, -400, 2, 12, 16]
```

For example:

```
stop = [1, 2]
ary2.slice_when{ |e| stop.include? e }
    .each_slice(2).map { |a, b| b.unshift(a.last) if b }
    .reject { |e| e.nil? || (e.intersection stop).empty? }

#=> [[1, 3, 2], [1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 7, 5, 2], [1, -400, 2]]
```

---

**Other option**

More verbose but clearer, given the input:

```
input =  %w(b a b c a b c a c b c a c a)
start = 'a'
stop  = 'b'
```

Using `Enumerable#each_with_object`, why not use the good old `if then else`?:

```
tmp = []
pickup = false
input.each_with_object([]) do |e, res|
  if e == start
    pickup = true
    tmp << e
  elsif pickup && e == stop
    tmp << e
    res << tmp
    tmp = []
    pickup = false
  elsif pickup
    tmp << e
  end
end

#=> [["a", "b"], ["a", "b"], ["a", "c", "b"]]

  [1]: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_when
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like an interview question. I'll explain the simplest algorithm I can think of:

You loop through the array once and build the output as you go. When you encounter `1`, you store it and the subsequent numbers into another temporary array. When you encounter `2`, you put the array in the output array. The edge cases are:

- another `1` after you start building the temporary array
- a `2` when you don't have a temporary array

First case is easy, always build a new temp array when you encounter a `1`. For the second one, you have to check whether you have any items in your temporary array and only append the temp array to your output if it's not empty.

That should get you started.

Comment: Thanks for that. This problem is not for a programing interview.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`chunk`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk) and Ruby's [flip-flop](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-Flip-Flop) operator:

```
input = [0, 1, 3, 2, 10, 1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 7, 5, 2, 3, 1, -400, 2, 12, 16]

input.chunk { |i| true if i==1..i==2 }.each { |_, ary| p ary }
```

Output:

```
[1, 3, 2]
[1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 7, 5, 2]
[1, -400, 2]
```

Comment: I like and dislike this solution at the same time. Because of the Flipflop :-)

Comment: @Pascal yeah, the flip-flop is an oddity. But it's surprisingly hard to find a replacement that's nearly as succinct.

Answer (score 1):

Since you commented and added that you are actually reading a file, I deleted my old answer (which was faulty anyways, as @Stefan pointed out) and cam up with this. You can paste this in a file and run it, the `DATA` IO contains everything that appears after `__END__`. In your application you would replace it with your File.

```rb
class Chunker
  BEGIN_INDICATOR = "BEGIN"
  END_INDICATOR = "END"

  def initialize(io)
    @io = io
  end

  def each
    return enum_for(:each) if !block_given?

    chunk = nil
    while !io.eof? do
      line = io.readline.chomp
      if line == BEGIN_INDICATOR
        chunk = []
        chunk << line
      elsif line == END_INDICATOR
        chunk << line
        yield chunk.freeze
        chunk = nil
      elsif chunk
        chunk << line
      end
    end
  end

  private

  attr_reader :io
end

chunker = Chunker.new(DATA)


chunker.each do |chunk|
  p chunk
end

# or, thanks to the `return enum_for(:each) if !block_given?` line:

chunker.each.with_index do |chunk, index|
  p "at #{index} is #{chunk}"
end



__END__
ignore
BEGIN
some
thing
END
BEGIN
some
other
thing
END
maybe ignore as well
´´´

You could enhance it to throw EOF when `each` is called multiple times or whatever suits your needs.
```

Answer (score 1):

For all people wanting to take a walk on the beach but for obvious reasons can't:

```
class Flipflop

  def initialize(flip, flop) #flip and flop being boolean-returning lambdas
    @state = false
    @flip  = flip
    @flop  = flop
  end

  def flipflop(x) #logic taken from The Ruby Programming Language page 111
    if !@state
      result = @flip[x]
      if result
        @state = !@flop[x]
      end
      result
    else
      @state = !@flop[x]
      true
    end
  end

end

ff = Flipflop.new( ->(x){x == 1}, ->(x){x == 2} )
input = [0, 1, 3, 2, 10, 1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 7, 5, 2, 3, 1, -400, 2, 12, 16]

res = input.select{|el| ff.flipflop(el) }.slice_before(1) #an Enumerator
p res.to_a
# =>[[1, 3, 2], [1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 7, 5, 2], [1, -400, 2]]
```

For strings, `ff = Flipflop.new( ->(x){x.chomp == "BEGIN"}, ->(x){x.chomp == "END"} )` or something like that should work.